# Quick way to insert a structured Map[String,Any] object into mongodb

Tags: mongodb, scala, casbah

I have a JSON-like scala object consisting of any recursive collection of: scala.collection.Map[String,Any], scala.collection.Seq[Any], plus the basic types: Int, Float, String, Double, Long, which I receive through a web API.

If I try to directly squirt this object into a mongodb with (e.g. with insert), it works if the object is a map[String,_] to non-collection types. But if the map values are themselves collections, then mongodb driver library loses its mind and goes into and infinite loop (stack overflow). What's the right way to take such an object and place it in the MongoDB.

(Have casbah, but looks mostly useful for building the object incrementally, not converting an existing object).

Here's a failing example:

```
val obj2= scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String,Any]()
obj2 += ("a" -> 123)

val obj1= scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String,Any]()    
obj1 += ("x" -> List(obj2) )    

val anyMapLike:scala.collection.Map[String,Any] = obj1
collection.insert( anyMapLike )   // Stack overflow here!
```

... goes bananas in:

```
 java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$MutableMapWrapper.underlying(Wrappers.scala:216)
    at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$MutableMapWrapper.productElement(Wrappers.scala:216)
    at scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime$$anon$1.next(ScalaRunTime.scala:185)
 ...
    at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder._putObjectField(BasicBSONEncoder.java:234)
    at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder.putIterable(BasicBSONEncoder.java:295)
    at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder._putObjectField(BasicBSONEncoder.java:234)
    at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder.putIterable(BasicBSONEncoder.java:295)
    at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder._putObjectField(BasicBSONEncoder.java:234)
    at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder.putIterable(BasicBSONEncoder.java:295)
 ...
```

Comment: Can you give an example map that's causing issues?

Comment: Gladly. Updated the above.

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue transforming mutable types into mongodb that caused a infinite loop error see: [SCALA-115](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SCALA-115) - a fix will be in the next release of Casbah.